# What reason could be for the F1 score that was not a harmonic mean of precision and recall

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dl4j

[![enter image description here][1]][1]What reason could be for the F1 score that was not a harmonic mean of precision and recall with macro-average weighted equally for multi-class? My dataset is imbalanced, and the predictions are skewed.

Comment: Not a programming question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

A [macro F1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) calculates metrics for each label and finds their unweighted mean. Means that it doesn't take class imbalance into account whereas, a [weighted macro F1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) calculates metrics for each label and finds their average weighted by the number of instances of each label. Hence, it accounts for class imbalance and can have a score not between precision and recall.

For an example of weighted F1, refer to this answer [Sandeep](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283961/where-does-sklearns-weighted-f1-score-come-from).